# How can I remove ...: command not found (newline) bash: .: .: is a directory ? It appears everytime when I open the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I was installing Julia and had to use
`nano ~/.bashrc` and then : . . .
`export PATH="$PATH:/home/sammy/julia-1.8.1/bin"`  inside bash. After finishing the work. I noticed:
`[...: command not found bash: .: .: is a directory while opening terminal

I asked chatgpt and it said: Check Startup Files: Open your home directory in the terminal and look for files like `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.profile`. These files are executed when you start a new terminal session.
but could not find any of the directory mentioned above .

Comment: It looks like you added `. . . export` (with 3 literal dots before the export). That's obviously an error. Please [edit] your question to include your newly added line from your `.bashrc` file _as text_ ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Comment: Start a new subshell using `bash -l -x`. You should get a trace of your startup and hopefully also the error message. The trace will show you, where the buggy line is.

Comment: PATH is already exported. There is no reason to export it again.